# should system calls be completed before context switch

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, posix

Is it guaranteed that system calls will be completed before context switch or preemption ? Should we expect that system call instructions are uninterruptible. Or is it depend on system call type or operating system implementations ?

Comment: On the contrary, system calls will often trigger context switching, assuming that the system call blocks waiting for some event.

Comment: is it possible to break system call block executions ?

Comment: @RedArrow No. The correct approach is to use the non-blocking versions of system calls. In this case, these system calls return control to the calling program immediately with an error code such as EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: @David ; i mean or i try to ask that when you are calling system calls such as open, read , write etc. is intervention of another software possible or not? i think i.e for open call that should be uninterruptible since system tables for file descriptors should stay consistent

Comment: Many of the file system functions will cause one or more context switches on most modern OS's. Are you asking if they are thread safe?

Comment: No such thing is guaranteed, ask your real question please.

Comment: @jwdonahue if those system calls thread safe what guarantees or not?

Comment: @Rarity i guess some mechanism should guarantee this. otherwise if your open call preempted then returned file descriptors retrieved from the system tables may be inconsistent. i think somehow it should be guaranteed that system calls are completed without any intervention.

Comment: Shared resources are protected in a way that only allows one process at a time to access the shared resource. That doesn't prevent the process that "owns" the shared resource from being preempted. It just means that another process that wants to use the resource must wait.

Comment: @RedArrow, you should take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE] before asking any more questions here.  So it seem that what you really want is information on the thread safety of your standard library and OS functions, and that really depends on the implementation.

Comment: @RedArrow "i guess ... should guarantee this. otherwise ... file descriptors ... may be inconsistent." -- nonsense, why you think that? Kernel thread may place request for open and go do other job. Think about opening NFS file, it starts by sending some packets to NFS server, nothing to do before the response arrives, so CPU will go do something else, 100% chance of preemption. You seem to have some wild idea about how kernel works and it makes you think strange things, try adding detailed description of possible error situation in your question, otherwise logic behind your doubts is unclear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that system calls will be completed before context switch or preemption

No, many system calls will actually cause context switches to happen, even in a single threaded application. Let's not forget that there are other processes running on most modern systems today, plus hardware interrupts and a host of asynchronous events.

> Or is it depend on system call type or operating system implementations ?

Yes, very much so.

> if those system calls thread safe what guarantees or not?

Read your system documentation.

Most C compiler tool chains include single and multi-threaded libraries. Even the single threaded libraries are context-switch safe, but not necessarily re-entrant from the same process. A context-switch is just that, the entire context of the current thread is switched out for a new one. As long as those threads aren't touching any shared resources (context overlap), there's nothing else to be concerned with. When you write multi-threaded applications however, you have to take responsibility for the resources that are shared between the threads that you own.  For the most part, good design avoids shared resources, but there can be critical paths where it is unavoidable.

Most modern operating systems have many internally shared resources, and they use various techniques to synchronize access to those. Locks, semaphores, critical sections, atomic operations (lock-free algorithms) are all common practice in multi-threaded environments. Application writers shouldn't ever need to worry about how the OS manages access to shared resources internally, so you can call `open`, `read` and `write`from your application, without concern, provided you are not sharing any handles between threads within your process.

When you write multi-threaded applications, you should use the thread-safe libraries supplied by your compiler tool chain. Thread-safe libraries use all of the same techniques that operating systems do, to protect internally shared resources, but they cannot protect you from yourself! If you share a resource between threads, such as a global variable, handle, buffers, even accesses to some kinds hardware registers, you must arrange to synchronize those accesses.

OS writers are responsible for protecting their own internally shared resources and documenting all thread-safety concerns.

Library writers are responsible for protecting their own internally shared resources and documenting all thread-safety concerns.

Application writers are responsible for protecting their own shared resources and documenting all process concurrency concerns (inter-process resource sharing).

Answer (score 1):

No. Lets say you are waiting for a socket read to complete. This can take seconds. Now if your single core cpu is to multi-task, you expect it to run other threads while waiting.